# Calculating uniform angles between 2 vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

If I have two vectors, say:

[100] and [101]

and I want to calculate two angles between them, uniformly distributed, would it just be:

[1 0 0.33] and [1 0 0.66]?

So,

[100] = 0 degrees
[101] = 45 degrees

Does this mean that:

[1 0 0.33] = 15 degrees?

and

[1 0 0.66] = 30 degrees?

Comment: That's not a physics question.

Comment: I tagged it as materials science

Comment: This is not a hw question

Comment: It is homework-like as per [our policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Comment: How would this even be materials science?

Comment: @KyleKanos: crystallography? In the days of my youth I spend many happy hours working out the angles between crystal lattice vectors (for a small and eccentric subset of definitions of the word *happy*).

Comment: Yes, it is crystallography. I'm not sure why we have to debate exactly how it relates to materials science. Why is my word not good enough?

Comment: Jackson, I don't really get what you're asking. Why are there two angles involved? Are you trying to work out the differences in the angles of azimuth and altitude? And what does *uniformly distributed* mean in this context. Forgive me if this is obvious to crystallographers, it was thirty years ago I last studied it.

Comment: I start with 2 angles. [100] and [101]. I just want two define two angles evenly spaced between them. That is all.

Comment: Aha I see. You mean take the plane that the two vectors lie in, then construct two more vectors in this plane so that the angles between adjacent vectors is one third of the angle between your original two vectors?

Comment: Right. I am essentially giving atoms energy and I want to rotate the angle in which it is imparted. I want to have 24 evenly spaced angles starting from [100] and working around the z-axis.

Comment: While I can see the origins in crystallography, this question isn't actually about that, it is purely a math question.

Comment: Are you saying physics does not have math?

Comment: What I am saying is that this site is about physics. If you have a math question, you can ask it on [math.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular case is easy, because we're working in the $xz$ plane so the sums are straightforward. The general case for two arbitrary vectors would be a lot harder.

Anyhow, let's take the particular example you describe:

[image: Vectors]

The angle (1 0 a) makes with (1 0 0) is just tan$^{-1}$(a) and the angle (1 0 b) makes is tan$^{-1}$(b). You want the $a$ angle to be 15° and the $b$ angle to be 30° so the two vectors are just (1 0 tan(15)) and (1 0 tan(30)).

Comment: Would the first angle above (101) be (tan(30) 0 1)

Comment: No, it would be (tan(30) 0 1) then (tan(15) 0 1) then (tan(0) 0 1), which is of course just (0 0 1). Draw in the vectors on my diagram to convince yourself of this.

Comment: I edited my comment while you were typing. I agree, tan(30) is right

Comment: Would the first vector past [100] be [-tan(15) 0 1]?

Comment: Construct all the other vectors by reflecting in the $x$ and $z$ axes. So reflecting (tan(15) 0 1) in the $z$ axis gives (-tan(15) 0 1) as you say. Reflect the other five vectors on the diagram to complete the top left quadrant. Then reflect all your vectors in the $x$ axis to complete the bottom half.

Comment: Just to be clear, the the first vector above [100] is 15 degrees offset right?

Comment: @JacksonHart: 15 degrees anticlockwise from [100]